# ot-ctl connect session failed: No such file or directory

Tags: openthread

otbr-agent.service is not running when checking status.

Please suggest how to fix.

I have only tried to browse other forms to find a solution, however it is still not clear to me how to fix this. I'm new to this so please be explicit in your answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? Are you running on a Raspberry Pi? Did you create a RCP/NCP?

Comment: I followed this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCyzNzYSG4U&ab_channel=WSN%26IoT

Running on Pi with RCP